# C read() and write() while loop

Tags: c, buffer, system, file-descriptor

Here is example code:

```
int nbajt; int buf[];

 // we opened file and get descriptor fd

 while ((nbajt = read(fd, buf, 5)) > 0) {
        if (write(fd2, buf, nlbajt) == -1) {
            perror("ERROR");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

I don't understand how it is working when we use while loop. How many times this loop will proceed? (times of the lengs of `buf`?). Will `nbajt` has only values of `1` or `0 + buf` file position will be changing 1 place after each loop step? So in first step we have `nlbajt = 1` and we take buf first position char and then write it to `fd2`?. On the end we have `nlbajt==0` so it means it's end of file? I would be grateful for checking if i am wrong.My main concern is how nbajt value is changing. How it is diffrent for this attitude:

```
nbajt = read(fd, buf, 5));
write(fd2, buf, sizeof(a));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The read() has the below prototype:

```
int  read(  int  handle,  void  *buffer,  int  nbyte );
```

It returns number of bytes successfully read . 0 when EOF is reached.-1 when there is an error.

Yes `nlbajt = 0` means EOF here.

Comment: I know that but what is happening when we use while loop? How is this nlbajt changing? How many times this loop proced?

Comment: @user3402584 Until the EOF is reached this loop will continue. Which means until the number of bytes read is greater than 0 your while loop passes. In your case it is 5 ytes in each loop so when EOF is reached your read() will return 0 so the condition fails and exits the loop